# Can't find variable: regeneratorRuntime

Tags: webpack, babeljs, babel-loader, babel-polyfill

I get the error

> Can't find variable: regeneratorRuntime

when I use

```
 {
   test: /node_modules(?:\/|\\).+\.js$/,
   loader: 'babel-loader',
   options: {
     presets: [['@babel/preset-env', {targets: 'last 2 versions, ie >= 10'}]],
     plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring', '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread', '@babel/plugin-transform-template-literals'],
    babelrc: false
    }
},
```

Once I change it to

```
 {
   test: /node_modules(?:\/|\\).+\.js$/,
   loader: 'babel-loader',
   options: {
     /*  presets: [['@babel/preset-env', {targets: 'last 2 versions, ie >= 10'}]],*/
     plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring', '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread', '@babel/plugin-transform-template-literals'],
      babelrc: false
   }
},
```

the problem is gone.

These are my dev-dependencies:

```
    "devDependencies": {
        "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.19",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.3.6",
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "css-loader": "^5.2.7",
        "eslint": "^7.30.0",
        "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
        "eslint-loader": "^4.0.2",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.18.0",
        "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.29",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.6.2",
        "postcss": "^8.3.8",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.4",
        "url-loader": "^4.0.0",
        "vue-loader": "^16.8.1",
        "webpack": "^5.54.0",
        "webpack-shell-plugin-next": "^2.2.2",
    },
```

[image: error]

So now my question is: Why does this error appear? A few weeks ago it did not. And why is `presets: [['@babel/preset-env', {targets: 'last 2 versions, ie >= 10'}]],` the problem?

Any hint or explanation is highly appreciated.